# Apache2 writes acces log but not errors log

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, log-files, apache2

My apache2 server writes to the vhost access log without issue but fails to write error logs.
The vhost is configured as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com
    Redirect permanent / https://sub.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
       ServerName sub.domain.com
       ServerAdmin administrator@domain.com
       DocumentRoot /home/webadmin/web/www.domain.com/
       <Directory /home/webadmin/web/www.domain.com/>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
                Allowoverride All
       </Directory>

       SSLEngine on
       SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.2017.crt
       SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.2017.key
       SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/domain.com.2017.ca.crt
       Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000"

       Customlog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs /home/webadmin/logs/www.domain.com/ex%y%m%d.log 86400" combined
       Errorlog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs /home/webadmin/logs/www.domain.com/er%y%m%d.log 86400"
</VirtualHost>
```

`apache2ctl -S` outputs:

```
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
         default server othersub.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/othersub.domain.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost othersub.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/othersub.domain.com.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost sub.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub.domain.com.conf:1)
*:443                  is a NameVirtualHost
         default server othersub.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/othersub.domain.com.conf:7)
         port 443 namevhost othersub.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/othersub.domain.com.conf:7)
         port 443 namevhost sub.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub.domain.com.conf:7)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

Any idea why the error logs fails to appear ?

Comment: Did you try to change the ErrorLog directive and did it change something? Also, how did you verify it does not log anything? What error were you expected there?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, there are no errors available for custom error log yet.

In `rotatelogs --help` this two options are interessting:

```
-f       Force opening of log on program start.
-c       Create log even if it is empty.
```

I tried on a testing machine on my site with this settings inside the *VirtualHost* tag:

```
Customlog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs -f /var/log/apache2/ex%y%m%d.log 86400" combined
Errorlog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs -f /var/log/apache2/er%y%m%d.log 86400"
```

Then a the *ex170925.log* appeared even though it was empty.